# How to fix 'rest_invalid_param' when tried to post a comment using wordpress API

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, curl

I'm trying to post a comment to a blog post using cURL, but ended up with 'rest_invalid_param' error.

I tried to run the same URL that I used in cURL in postman and it is working good. I don't know where I'm going wrong.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/aapta-blog/wp-json/wp/v2/comments");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = array(
'author_email' => urlencode($user_email),
'author_name' => urlencode($user_name),
'content' => urlencode($content),
'post' => urlencode($post_id)
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
die();
```

I even tried to json_encode($data), but still getting the error.
What I'm passing in postman is http://example.com/aapta-blog/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?author_email=novusflos.web@gmail.com&author_name=Danu&content=Test from postman2&post=38

Error:

```
{
  code: "rest_invalid_param",
  message: "Invalid parameter(s): post",
  data: {
    status: 400,
    params: {
      post: "post is not of type integer."
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

URL encoding may be tripping it up in cURL.  Maybe try this.

```
$data = json_encode( 

     array(
      'author_email' => $user_email,
      'author_name' => $user_name,
      'content' => $content,
      'post' => $post_id
     )
);



$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/aapta-blog/wp-json/wp/v2/comments");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
die();
```

Comment: Not working. Post id error.

{
code: "rest_comment_invalid_post_id",
message: "Sorry, you are not allowed to create this comment without a post.",
data: {
status: 403
}
}

Comment: Where are you passing in the post_id?  Can you share that part of your code?